# Encontrar elementos con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Buenas tardes masters

Eh estado intentando llegar a un elemento con jquery pero no doy quizá me puedan ayudar

con muchas cajas con los mismos atributos y quiero llegar desde #desde_aqui hasta #quiero llegar aquí

```
<div class="card negociaciones" style="border:0">
<div class="card-body" style="padding:0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="" width="36" height="36"alt="">
            <span><strong>'.$cacadevaca2.' :</strong> </span>

        </div>
        <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-end botones">
            <i class="fas fa-reply ml-2" id="desde_aqui" data-comment="50" style="color:#ffc107; cursor:pointer" title="Responder"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mb-2">
            <p>contenido</p>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-12 respuestas ">
            <div class="form-group d-none quiero_llegar_aqui">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" rows="1" placeholder="Escribe tu comentario">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

este es jquery del boton

```
    $(document).on('click', '#desde_aqui', function(event) {
      alert('message?: DOMString')
})
```

y togglear la clase d-none los .card son generados con php y jquery

pero no se como salirme y bucar

Comment: Bienvenido Daniel. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué significa que quieres llegar *desde aquí hasta aquí*  y qué quieres hacer? ¿Qué quieres decir por toglearl a clase? ¿Qué quiere decir que no sabes como salirte y buscar?

Answer (score 1):

Me sumo al comentario que no se entiende bien la pregunta, pero te dejo un codigo de ejemplo que tal vez te guíe en lo que necesitas.

```
<div class="card negociaciones" style="border:0">
<div class="card-body" style="padding:0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="" width="36" height="36" alt="">
            <span>
                <strong>'.$cacadevaca2.' :</strong>
            </span>

        </div>
        <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-end botones">
            <i class="fas fa-reply ml-2" id="desde_aqui" data-comment="50" style="color:#ffc107; cursor:pointer" title="Responder">aqui</i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mb-2">
            <p>contenido</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 respuestas ">
            <div class="form-group d-none quiero_llegar_aqui">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" rows="1" placeholder="Escribe tu comentario">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#desde_aqui', function (event) {
        var title = $('#desde_aqui').attr("title");
        $('.quiero_llegar_aqui').append(title);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hola aunque ya te comentaron la respuest arriba te doy otra si necesitas encontrar un elemento con jquery puedes usar la funcion **.find()** de jquery.

ejemplo sencillo:

```js
$( "li.item-ii" ).find( "li" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<ul class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii">II
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-3">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

si necesitas buscarla por attributo?

lo puees hacer de la siguiente manera:

```js
$( "input[value='Hot Fuzz']" ).next().text( "Hot Fuzz" );
```

igualmente si lo quieres buscar por clase el elemento puedes buscarlo de esta manera:

```js
$( ".myClass" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
```

si quieres mas informacion de como buscar/selecionar un elemento mira este recurso en ingles :

[using jquery by find a element](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

aqui tienes un ejemplo sencillo con el que te puedes basar :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  
  
<ul class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii">II
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-3">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>

  

<script>

 $( "li.item-ii" ).find( "li" ).css( "background-color", "red" );

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

y si te interesa hacerlo desde JS mira esta funcion :
[encontrar/obtener un elemento con JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)